# No associated accounts shown in CV status

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linked-accounts

I've read some questions about this topic but still haven't found an answer.
I recently created a CV in Stack Overflow Careers, but on `my CV` => `status` it says "No associated accounts". When I go to the `accounts` tab, though, my Stack Overflow and Meta accounts are visible, with the `Hide from CV` options and all. How do I make them appear on my CV?

**edit**: here are screenshots of both pages:

[image: my CV / status page on Stack Overflow Careers]

[image: my CV / accounts page on Stack Overflow Careers]

Comment: Screenshot of the "no associated accounts" error? Have you tried hiding then showing to see if it fixes the problem?

Comment: I tried hiding, then showing. No luck.. I'm adding the screenshots now...

Comment: 1. Are you logged in with your SO OpenId as the message suggests? 2. Is it possible that the accounts thing showing up is a feature of a paid account? (I don't have that check box thing on mine.)

Comment: 1. I used my Google OpenID for creating both accounts. 2. I have no idea... what checkbox thing are you talking about?

Comment: Errr.. not a checkbox. The "no associated accounts" item -- I don't have that in the list on mine.

Comment: Oh. Hmmmmmmm :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently introduced a bug in Careers which caused associated accounts to not show up for some accounts. It was related to a recent mostly-under-the-hood overhaul of associations code across the Stack Exchange network.

It's fixed now, so your associated trilogy accounts should be showing up on your CV again. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's showing up now, thanks a lot!!